# Same node group when there are 2 datanodes and RF is 1 in mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I followed [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-install-configuration.html) tutorial and it works fine. This is the what I get when I `show`ed in ndb_mgm client.

```
ndb_mgm> show
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @1.1.1.10  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
id=3    @1.1.1.8  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @1.1.1.5  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @1.1.1.9  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)
id=5    @1.1.1.11  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)
```

That's fine.

Then I changed **NoOfReplicas=1** in config.ini of managemant node, and restarted all nodes.

Now I expect 2 nodegroups according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-nodes-groups.html).

`[number_of_node_groups] = number_of_data_nodes / NoOfReplicas`

But I still get the same output for `show` command in ndb_mgm client.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably should have posted this question on [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just found the same question there unanswered. :( 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/all-four-data-nodes-in-mysql-cluster-in-same-node-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since I found what has been gone wrong. When we change `config.ini` in management node we have to do 2 things.

1) Restart Management node with `--reload` option

2) Restart data nodes with `--initial` option

Now my SHOW output is as follows.

```
ndb_mgm> show
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @1.1.1.10  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
id=3    @1.1.1.8  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2, Nodegroup: 1)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @1.1.1.5  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @1.1.1.9  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)
id=5    @1.1.1.11  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2)
```

Comment: Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-nodes-groups.html. might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks a lot like mysql cluster bug#30831 - in that datanodes are still 'starting' and nodegroup(s) > 0 are reported as 0: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30831

You don't say, but I'm assuming the correct nodegroups are reported eventually.

Comment: If it is starting, it should be like `id=2 @1.1.1.10  (mysql-5.6.11 ndb-7.3.2, starting, Nodegroup: 0, Master)` right? But in my case it is not. (see my SHOW output in the question.)

Comment: Yes - my bad. Missed the fact that your status is slightly different from the case linked at dba.stackexchange.com.